# Unable to click on the button when running in TestNG, but works fine when running in main() method

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a project where in I have a button "Add New Client". I located the element using the ID and selenium clicks on the element without any trouble when I run it in main() method.

The same code when I run through TestNG, I get NoSuchElement exception. I cannot give the URL but here is the HTML.

```
<a id="BtnAddNew" class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" role="button" style="right: auto; left: 389px; margin: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <span id="BtnAddNew-btnWrap" class="x-btn-wrap" unselectable="on">
        <span id="BtnAddNew-btnEl" class="x-btn-button">
            <span id="BtnAddNew-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center" unselectable="on">Add New Client</span>
            <span id="BtnAddNew-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon-el " style="" unselectable="on" role="img"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you share the way you are locating the element? Just a sanity check, does adding `Thread.sleep()` before searching for an element make any difference?

Comment: When running in `public static void main()` I identify the element using xpath `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='combobox-1052-inputEl']")).click();` 

When running through TestNG, the same locator does not get identified.

Comment: Could it be that the `1052` number is dynamically assigned?